# ASP.NET website on localhost errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, localhost, parse-error

When running my ASP.NET website on localhost i get the following errors..

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/MPage.master' does not exist.

Line 1:  <%@ page title="" language="VB" masterpagefile="~/MPage.master" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="Page1, App_Web_rscnlqny" %>
```

I can fix this by using:

```
<%@ page title="" language="VB" masterpagefile="./MPage.master" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="Page1, App_Web_rscnlqny" %>
```

But after doing this I get the error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_hipf5z3e'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Line 1:  <%@ master language="VB" inherits="MPage, App_Web_hipf5z3e" %>
```

How do I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you've taken a pre-compiled aspx page and edited it as if uncompiled, such as copying it from the Live server and overwriting your dev/working version.

On the first line of your aspx page within the `<%@Page />` tag you'll probably see an attribute like:

```
inherits="yourPageClass, App_Web_hipf5z3e".
```

Delete the `App_Web_XXXX` part and add the CodeFile attribute pointing to your code behind file:

```
CodeFile="yourPageFile.aspx.cs"
```

*New Answer:*

`You can mix C# and VB in the same project...but not the same page.`

*Edit Web.config*

```
<compilation debug="false">
   <codeSubDirectories>
       <add directoryName="VBCode"/>
       <add directoryName="CSCode"/>
   </codeSubDirectories>
</compliation>
```

Comment: Now I get:                                                             Parser Error Message: The language of the code file is inconsistent with the language of the page.

    Line 1:  <%@ master language="VB" inherits="MPage" CodeFile="MPage.master.cs" %>

Comment: but in your code file you are using c# - `CodeFile="MPage.master.cs"`

Comment: mine is vb -  CodeFile="MPage.master.vb"